# I have two identical answers for a coding question in Python and C++ but somehow Python passes all the testcases and C++ solution doesn't

Tags: python, c++, string, binary, cp

The question is -

A large binary number is represented by a string A of size N and comprises of 0s and 1s. You must perform a cyclic shift on this string. The cyclic shift operation is defined as follows:

If the string **A** is **[A0, A1, A2, A3,....., An-1, An]** then after performing one cyclic shift, the string becomes **[A1, A2, A3,....., An-1, An, A0]**.

You performed the shift infinite number of times and each time you recorded the value of the binary number represented by the string. The maximum binary number formed after performing (possibly 0) the operation is **B**. Your task is to determine the number of cyclic shifts that can be performed such that the value represented by the string **A** will be equal to **B** for the **Kth** time.

Input format

- First line: A single integer **T** denoting the number of test cases
- For each test case:

  - First line: Two space-separated integers **N** and **K**
  - Second line: **A** denoting the string

Output format

For each test case, print a single line containing one integer that represents the number of cyclic shift operations performed such that the value represented by string **A** is equal to **B** for the **Kth** time.

> C++ code for the problem:-

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t){
        int n, k;
        cin>>n>>k;
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        string max = "";
        int p = -1;
        int d, res;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(s>max){
                max = s;
                d = i;
            }
            else if(s==max){
                p = i-d;
                break;
            }
            s = s.substr(1) + s.substr(0,1);
        }
        if(p==-1){
            res = d + ((k-1)*n);
        }
        else{
            res = d + ((k-1)*p);
        }
        cout<<res<<endl;
        t--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Python Code for the problem :-

```
t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    n, k = map(int, input().split())
    s = input()
    max = ""
    p = -1
    for i in range(n):
        if max < s:
            max = s
            d = i
        elif max == s:
            p = i - d
            break
        s = s[1:] + s[:1]
    if p == -1:
        print(d + (k-1)*n)
    else:
        print(d + (k-1)*p)
    print("")
```

*You can find question here [Cyclic Shift](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/)*

Can anybody debug the problem with C++ code?

Comment: Well, the problem statement is very clear about input being _line-based_ but your C++ program is not making _any_ attempt to do line-based input.

Comment: @paddy That seems not to be the problem. Both codes do the same. I checked with some test cases. But, in my opinion both are wrong. But for this I would need some example input and output

Comment: The python version prints an extra newline at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your C++ code works.

I entered it [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/de/problem/algorithm/maximum-binary-number-cb9a58c1/)

The result was OK. See:

[image]

But maybe I do not understand your question . . .

Comment: Yes it is passing the sample test case but when you submit it, it shows exceeded time limit for some cases for C++ code, but that is not the case for python.